# Dell inspirion14 audio output and input didn't work after install ubuntu15.10

Tags: sound, alsa

My ALSA information is located [here...](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=223c907861c2850a928827843884a99a6ec2178c)

[image]

```
$ aplay -l：

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****

card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3234 Analog [ALC3234 Analog]    
  Subdevices: 0/1    
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]

  Subdevices: 1/1    
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1    
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]    
  Subdevices: 1/1    
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Who can give some advice to solve the problem？